# Wrap title and excerpt in a div (latest posts block)

Tags: php, themes, html

I am trying to achieve to following the desing with the latest posts block:

[image]

On the left is the features image, on the right the categories, title, excerpt and a read-more button.

This is what I got so far:

[image]

My issue is that title and excerpt are not wrapped in a div and therefor placed in a row when using `display: flex`. Is there a possibility to wrap title `<a>` and excerpt `<div>` in a div?

[image]

Furthermore I am curious if there is a possibility to display the category in the latest posts bock. There is no such option for that block:

[image]

Is it possible to add this feature via the functions.php?

```
enter code here
```

Comment: if you instead use a query block, you can composer its contents with featured image and title blocks, and use the layout options of a group block or columns to get what you want without writing any code

Comment: @TomJNowell that sounds like a great idea. I'll try that :)